# PHP If condition between two times

Tags: php

I have a case where a box of text should not be shown between two times for example 20 and 01 (24-hour clock), but it should also work, when i choose not to show the box betweem 20 and 22 for example.

But if I have:

```
$start = "20";
$end = "01";
$now = date('H');

if($now > $start AND $now < $end) {
  echo "DONT SHOW THE BOX";
} else {
  echo "SHOW THE BOX";
}
```

How can I convert the numbers, can I use `mktime()` even if I don't have a date? Because the box should be activated every day in that time range.

Comment: Your code should work fine. But you can always typecast it like `(int)$start` or you can also use `intval($start)`.

Comment: Hi choz, yes the code are working but the problem is when its between 20 and 01, i want it not to show anything. If i test the if function between 20 and 01 it will print "SHOW THE BOX" and it's supposed to print "DONT SHOW THE BOX". I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I get what you mean. Check the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You **don't want** to show the box between 20:00 to 01:00

Currently your logic is kinda messed up in `if($now > $start AND $now < $end)`.

If you expect `$start = 20` and `$end = 1`, **Then what kind of value is `$now` that might be MORE than `20` AND LESS than `1`.**

Your if statement logic will always go to **`ELSE`** whatever the value of `$now` is.

But there's another workaround to switch the logic like this.

> You **want** to show the box between 02:00 to 19:00

Instead of the other way around.

So you can do this,

```
$start = "20";
$end = "01";
$now = date('H');

if ($now > $end && $now < $start)
{
    echo "SHOW THE BOX";
}
else
{
    echo "DON'T SHOW";
}
```

**Update 1:**

> Now, you **don't** want to show the box between 20:00 to 22:00

You can do the vice versa or which is your current logic. Like,

```
$start = "20";
$end = "22";
$now = date('H');

if ($now >= $start && $now <= $end)
{
    echo "DON'T SHOW";
}
else
{
    echo "SHOW THE BOX";
}
```

**Update 2:**

If the `$start` or `$end` varies, you can always wrap them in another if condition. Like,

```
if ($start > $end)
{
    if ($now > $end && $now < $start)
    {
        echo "SHOW THE BOX";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "DON'T SHOW";
    }
}
else if ($start < $end)
{
    if ($now >= $start && $now <= $end)
    {
        echo "DON'T SHOW";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "SHOW THE BOX";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats great, but my problem is then, what if i want the box not be shown between 20 and 22 instead of 20 and 01?

Comment: @RasmusKjeldsen Then you may do it like `if ($now >= 20 && $now <= 22) { //dont show da box } else {}`, which is your current logic.

Comment: But would'nt that just send me back to where i started so i again have the problem if the time is between 20 and 01 again? I really would like it, so i just set a start time and end time, and whether it is night or day, if figures it out.

Comment: @RasmusKjeldsen You should edit your question. I will try to update my answer soon.

Comment: @RasmusKjeldsen Please check my updated answer. Btw, you should still edit your question since it's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Won't your code fail if the end hour is smaller than the start hour? I.e. if I use `$start = 4`, `$end = 1` for 4am till 1am it should output 'Yes' if I use `$now = 5` but your current code will output 'No'

Comment: @VirtualPigeon You're right. Thx for noticing it. I removed it since it would just use the same 2nd update method.

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't very pretty, but I think this is what you are after?

```
define('START_TIME', 6);
define('END_TIME', 1);

$startTime = new DateTime();
$startTime->setTime(START_TIME, 0);

$endTime = clone $startTime;
if (START_TIME > END_TIME) {
    $endTime->modify('+1 day');
}
$endTime->setTime(END_TIME, 0);

$currentTime = new DateTime();

if ($currentTime > $startTime && $currentTime < $endTime) {
    echo 'Show box';
} else {
    echo 'Don\'t show box';
}
```

You can alter the hours to decide the start/end hour for when to show/hide. If the ending hour is a lower hour than the starting hour then it will presume the ending hour should be the next day.

It could potentially be cleaned up a bit, but I'll leave that in your hands if it is what you're after.

Answer (score -1):

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Stockholm");
$setdate = ['14-05-2022','15-05-2022','16-05-2022'];
print_r($setdate)."<br>";
foreach ($setdate as $value) {
    $date= date("d-m-Y");
    if($date == $value){
        // echo "set Data For Product";
        // die();
    }
}
```